# Is it possible to reliably determine that a QueryException in Apex is a Row Lock Exception?

Tags: apex, locking

I'd like to create a standard in my company for handling concurrency in asynchronous processes. For this I need to reliably detect a row locking exception and differentiate it from any other kind of query exception. Only then can I know that I need to retry.

It seems that all I have is a QueryException with some English text, but I cannot rely on that English text to detect the source of the exception.

Is there any way that I can **reliably** determine that a query exception is due to locking issues? (Maybe I could time it?)

Comment: Our code assumes that a `QueryException` means there has been a timeout, caused by concurrency and locking. We are happy with this because it's then just a matter of indicating to the initiator that a retry is required, in a separate transaction. I'm guessing that `QueryException` could be thrown if there are other underling ORA issues, but I've not personally seen this in any context where we care about the exception.

Comment: @PhilW I'm pretty sure ORA issues come up as UnexpectedException, though it's been a while since I've run into one of these.

Comment: I'll have to look into the effect of WITH SYSTEM_MODE as that can produce errors on lack of permissions. There's a map I can get with the unavailable fields so it may be as simple as checking that is empty.

Comment: I use the english text in our org but one could do async retry on all QueryException with a retry counter, giving up after _n_ attempts